# cakePHP 4 Entity saving only works the second time

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 18n localization, if that matters. I've tried everything, but I just don't understand what the problem is.
CoursesCategoriesController.php

```
public function add()
    {
        $model = 'CoursesCategories';

        if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'kz'){
            $this->$model->setLocale('kz');
        }elseif(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'en'){
            $this->$model->setLocale('en');
        }else{
            $this->$model->setLocale('ru');
        }

        if( $this->request->is('post') ){
            $data = $this->request->getData();

            $entity = $this->$model->newEntity($data);
            if( $entity->getErrors() ){

                $errors = $entity->getErrors();
                foreach( $errors as $index => $err ){
                    $this->Flash->error( $err[array_key_first($err)] );
                }
                return $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
            }
            if( $this->$model->save($entity) ){
                $this->Flash->success(__('Данные успешно сохранены'));
                return $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
            } else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Ошибка сохранения данных'));
            }
        }
    }
```

but if I add another save before "if", then the first one doesn't work, but the second one already works:

```
$this->$model->save($entity)
if( $this->$model->save($entity) ){
```

CoursesCategoriesTable.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * CoursesCategories Model
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory newEmptyEntity()
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory newEntity(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory findOrCreate($search, ?callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory[] patchEntities(iterable $entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false saveMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface saveManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false deleteMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\CoursesCategory[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface deleteManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 */
class CoursesCategoriesTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('courses_categories');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Translate', [
            'fields' => [
                'title',
            ],
            'allowEmptyTranslations' => false
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('title')
            ->allowEmptyString('title');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Entity - CourseCategory.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * CoursesCategory Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string|null $title
 */
class CoursesCategory extends Entity
{
    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'title' => true,
    ];
}
```

Template:

```
<section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Добавление</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>

<?php echo $this->Form->create(null); ?>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Данные</h3>
                    <div class="card-tools">
                        <a href="/admin/courses_categories" type="button" class="btn btn-tool">
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body form_cols">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputTitle">Название категории</label>
                        <?= $this->Form->text('title', array('id' => 'inputTitle', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit_row">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->button('Добавить', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ci9P.png)
Debug $data:

```
APP/Controller\Admin\CoursesCategoriesController.php (line 79)
[
  'title' => '11111111',
]
```

What am I missing?

`I just don’t understand what the reason is, I’ve probably already looked at all the files and tried everything I know`

Comment: The bit where you're outputting all the errors should happen inside the "failed to save" block. It's possible for data to pass the initial validation, so have no errors right after patching, but then fail some other rule and not save for that reason. Might not apply here, as you haven't shown any other rules, but still good practice.

Comment: @GregSchmidt May be. But the problem I have is that saving only works when you use it again. That is, if I write $this->$model->save($entity), then it does not work, but if I repeat it twice: 
$this->$model->save($entity); //not working
$this->$model ->save($entity); // now it work 
then it is saved to the database.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen anything like that, so I don't have a solution for you. I'd suggest looking at your `beforeSave` function to see if it's doing anything that might change the state from one save attempt to the next, but it seems from the code you've shown that you don't have one. Have you got triggers or stored procedures at the database level that might be interacting with things here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out somehow. In the end, for everything to work, you need to do this:

```
class CoursesCategory extends Entity
{
    use TranslateTrait;
    // use TranslateStrategyTrait;
    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'title' => true,
        '_translations' => true
    ];
}
```

and controller add:

```
public function add(){
    $model = 'CoursesCategories';

    if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'kz'){
        $this->CoursesCategories->setLocale('kz');
    }elseif(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'en'){
        $this->CoursesCategories->setLocale('en');
    }else{
        $this->CoursesCategories->setLocale('ru');
    }

    if( $this->request->is('post') ){
        $data = $this->request->getData();
        $courseCategory = $this->CoursesCategories->newEmptyEntity();
        $courseCategory->translation($this->CoursesCategories->getLocale())->set($data);
        if( $this->$model->save($courseCategory) ){
            $this->Flash->success(__('Данные успешно сохранены'));
            return $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
        } else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('Ошибка сохранения данных'));
        }
    }
}
```

controller edit:

```
public function edit($item_id = null){
    if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'kz'){
        $this->CoursesCategories->setLocale('kz');
    }elseif(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'en'){
        $this->CoursesCategories->setLocale('en');
    }else{
        $this->CoursesCategories->setLocale('ru');
    }
    $CoursesCategories = $this->CoursesCategories->get($item_id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $new_data = $this->request->getData();
        // $old_data = clone $data;

        $CoursesCategories->translation($this->CoursesCategories->getLocale())->set($new_data);
        if( $CoursesCategories->getErrors() ){
            $errors = $CoursesCategories->getErrors();
            foreach( $errors as $index => $err ){
                $this->Flash->error( $err[array_key_first($err)] );
            }
            return $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
        }

        $new_data = $CoursesCategories->toArray();
        $this->CoursesCategories->patchEntity($CoursesCategories, $new_data);

        if ($this->CoursesCategories->save($CoursesCategories)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Изменения сохранены'));
            return $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Ошибка сохранения'));
    }
    $this->set( compact('CoursesCategories') );
}
```